# Preserving actual structure of essay while inserting into SQL server with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This might be a dumb question, and I am here with some google research.

Problem : I am trying to insert an essay(say blog post) in the sql table. I am able to retrieve it too to display on web page. However when I retrieve the whole content to display, it is totally trimmed of whitespaces.

before inserting into SQL, this will be the format of essay :

List of best cities in the world

- NY
- AZ
- LDN

After Inserting, while retrieving it appears like below

List of best cities in the world - NY -AZ -LDN

Thus I wish to know if anyone here do know how i can have this problem solved ?

Thank you all

Comment: Are you sure that you are saving the html tags in the text? When you look at the content of the record in the database do you see, for example the `<ul><li>`?

Comment: @Icarus thanks for the reply and no i have not included them in my document, so i will be able to preserve the structure with usual html tags, can i also mix up css ? bootstrap blockquote classes too ?

Comment: @santhoshkumarB I have posted my answer, Let me know if it helps

Comment: @santhos that explains why you don't see the structure being preserved as others have pointed out in their answer; however, BE VERY careful with this as is typically not a good idea to allow users to enter any html tag as you will make your site prone to XSS attacks. If you must accept HTML make sure you use a good library to sanitize it before saving it to the database

Comment: Which input control are you using on UI? Stackoverflow already has this feature, Your Essay is similar to question and answer posted here?

Comment: @AnilKumar am currently using a textarea input, was trying to keep it simple but now in understand that i got to do more, which input control would you suggest ? anything easier, thin, faster type ? Thank you

Comment: @Icarus understood, thank you for your explanation, finally, which library would you suggest ? if you had already used any

Comment: Santosh, you'll find many text editor plugins use them .. There are many free plugins

Comment: @Reddyyes found and already integrated it, thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save the `essay as a HTML` ie: you need to insert the complete HTML part of it and not only the text.

- NY
- AZ
- LDN

Should be saved into Db as

```
<ul>
 <li>NY</li>
 <li>AZ</li>
 <li>LDN</li>
</ul>
```

Later while displaying you need to append this as an HTML.

If you are using webForms then you need to do this

```
<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlDataFromDB) %>
```

Else if you are using MVC Razor syntax then use

```
  @Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(Model.htmlDataFromDB))
```

OR

```
@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.htmlDataFromDB))
```

But if you are in a edit mode and want to display back the essay in a TextArea then you dont have to worry about rendering it back, you could just do,

```
 @Html.TextArea("Essay", Model.htmlDataFromDB,13, 40, new { @class = "someClass"})
```

So note that everything depends on `How you save the HTML into the DB`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply, so do you mean to suggest that whole text should be equipped with front end design tags to ensure similar replication ? I am using repeater to borrow the content of the whole blog...like this   <p><%#Eval("Content")%></p> . so how do i modify this if i have to retrieve the html tagged content inserted in sql

Comment: possibly `<p><%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(#Eval("Content")) %></p>` , I am not into webforms so excuse for small syntax issues

Comment: this is webform only. i think this should work. can we also include css styling ? bootstrap classes ? divs ?

Comment: Yes, No problem at all

Answer (score 2):

In asp you probably have

```
<ul>
   <li>NY</li>
   <li>AZ<li>
   <li>LDN<li>
</ul>
```

Either you save the string with the tags include it

or you save it as rows and recreate the style after reading the db.